# Issue while implementing serialization in java

Tags: java, serialization

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Employee implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private HHPEmployee hhp;

    public Employee(String name, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public HHPEmployee getHhp() {
        return hhp;
    }
    public void setHhp(HHPEmployee hhp) {
        this.hhp = hhp;
    }

}
```

Subclass

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class HHPEmployee extends Employee{




    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HHPEmployee(String name, int id) {
        super(name,id);


    }
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



}
```

Serializing the objects-

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class stringObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HHPEmployee e = new HHPEmployee("G", 2000);
        Employee emp = new Employee("A", 4876);
        emp.setHhp(e);
        FileOutputStream file = null;
        ObjectOutputStream str = null;
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream("src/EmployeeByteStream.ser");
            str = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
            str.writeObject(emp);

            str.close();
            file.close();

            System.out.println("object has been serialized");

//          emp.setId(2000);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Deserializing the byte stream-

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class deserialObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileInputStream file;
        ObjectInputStream in;
        try {
            file = new FileInputStream("src/EmployeeByteStream.ser");
            in = new ObjectInputStream(file);

            Employee emp = (Employee) in.readObject();
            System.out.println(emp.getId());
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
            System.out.println(emp.getHhp().getName());
            System.out.println(emp);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }

}
```

1. Why am I getting `null` for `System.out.println(emp.getHhp().getName());` even though I am setting the value?
2. Also, while deserializing the byte stream, no where I am using `serialVersionUID`. So how does `serialVersionUID` helps in restricting the whole info to be transmitted?
3. The subclasses need not implement serializable right?
4. Does the receiver of the serialized data need to be aware of the classes for which he is deserializing the data ?

Comment: Please note: you should ask one question per question. And that serial version id exists since more than 20. Meaning: there are really plenty of tutorials that explain that thing to you. You are expected to do serious research prior posting questions here, so why do you need to ask about things that are documented extensively?!

Comment: Noted. Though I had checked the tutorials, I was not able to understand. Now I am clear. Didn't deserve a -1. :(

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use Java Serialization, it's nasty. To answer you questions:

1. Your constructor just sends the name to the superclass and does not initialise the `HHPEmployee` `name` field. Nothing to do with serialisation. Try it without.
2. `serialVersionUID` is a magic constant accessed using reflection by the Java Serialization mechanism. Other fields and methods used similarly are `serialPersistentFields`, `readObject`, `readObjectNoData`, `writeObject`, `readResolve` and `writeReplace`.
3. Yes. Though subclassing all over the place might not help clarity.
4. Well. It needs to load the class and all dependent classes (which needn't be documented, just for extra fun - try writing a whitelist going by spec instead of implementation...). `ObjectInputStream` itself just has a walk down the stack to find the first non-bootstrap class loader.  RMI (not now by default!) will take any random URL of the stream's choosing and start loading classes from there.

I also strongly recommend using try-with-resource.

Comment: Thanks. I could solve the point 1. Not able to understand 2 and 4. Normally in posts I have read, that the buyer will receive the `serialVersionId` only when the payment is made . Where does it apply exaclty?

Comment: @user1896796 I don't know what you mean by "buyer" and "payment" in this context. `serialVersionUID` is written to the stream; when the stream is read back, it's checked to make sure it agrees with the named class. So if you wrote the stream as is, modified the value to `2L` and reread the stream, then an exception would be thrown.

Comment: I am for sure not a Java newbie, and I have to agree: your point 4 doesn't make sense. Maybe you should focus on the question that was asked, instead of cramping 5 different aspects into one poor sentence... Especially given the fact that you are answering to a newbie user.

Comment: I tried changing the serialVersionId, I got `java.io.InvalidClassException` . Though I got the point. But my whole exception reads as `java.io.InvalidClassException: Employee; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3, local class serialVersionUID = 2` . Doesn't it already tells you that the UID should be 3L not 2L.

Comment: @user1896796 If this class is incompatible, no the `serialVersionUID` shouldn't be changed. You simply can't load the data, and it should fail fast rather than coming up with some random error or doing something very odd. `serialVersionUID` should only remain the same if the class' serialised form remains compatible. IMO, the practice of claiming compatibility with everything by using the same number everywhere, even during internal development, is unhelpful.